# Styling Inner Elements in XAML Style

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-store-apps

i have this code

```
<HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource HyperLink-Navi-Container}">
      <HyperlinkButton.Content>
             <TextBlock Text="Sample Text"></TextBlock>
      </HyperlinkButton.Content>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

and this style

```
<Style x:Key="HyperLink-Navi-Container" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1, 0.5" EndPoint="1, 2">
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.75"></GradientStop>
                <GradientStop Color="Gray"></GradientStop>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,2,2,0"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange"></Setter>

</Style>
```

now my question is how to style the properties of the **TextBlock** or any other elements inside the **HyperlinkButton** just like in CSS

```
HyperlinkButton.*
{
  Background : red;
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve background property using binding

Add this to TextBlock:

```
{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type HyperlinkButton}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TextBlock` doesn't have a `Background` property to set. You'll need to wrap it in another control, `Border` for example:

```
<HyperlinkButton.Content>
    <Border Background="Red">
        <TextBlock Text="Sample Text"></TextBlock>
    </Border>
</HyperlinkButton.Content>
```

Of course you can also use a style to set border background:

```
<Style x:Key="HyperlinkBorder" TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</Style>

<HyperlinkButton.Content>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource HyperlinkBorder}">
        <TextBlock Text="Sample Text"></TextBlock>
    </Border>
</HyperlinkButton.Content>
```

EDIT:

You can't affect nested elements from a style od an outer element in XAML. You could set the `ContentTemplate` in the style though:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="HyperlinkTemplate">
    <Border Background="Red">
        <TextBlock Text="Sample Text"></TextBlock>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<Style x:Key="HyperLink-Navi-Container" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1, 0.5" EndPoint="1, 2">
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.75"></GradientStop>
                <GradientStop Color="Gray"></GradientStop>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,2,2,0"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource HyperlinkTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Hi, i use Background as a sample only.. my point is how to access the element inside the element in Style

Comment: @VincentDagpin I don't know a lot about CSS so I'm guessing a bit what you're trying to achieve. Maybe setting `ContentTemplate` in the style is what you're looking for. See my edited answer.